# JavaScript Timer date not Valid when using correct format

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a string that is put together by cookies inputted by the user in a form. this is the code:

```js
var monthCookie     = getCookieValue("monthUserPref")
var dayCookie       = getCookieValue("dayUserPref")
var hourCookie      = getCookieValue("hourUserPref")
var minuteCookie    = getCookieValue("minuteUserPref")
var ampmCookie      = getCookieValue("ampmUserPref")
var currentYear     = new Date().getFullYear();
var monthCookie     = getMonth(monthCookie);

var currentEndDateForClockNoTZChange = "'"+currentYear+", "+monthCookie+", "+dayCookie+", "+hourCookie+", "+minuteCookie+", 0'"

var endTimeNoOffset = new Date(currentEndDateForClockNoTZChange)
var endTimeOffset   = endTimeNoOffset.getTimezoneOffset();

alert("Put together time is "+currentEndDateForClockNoTZChange)
alert(endTimeNoOffset)
alert("month cookie reads '"+monthCookie+"', day cookie reads '"+dayCookie+"', hour cookie reads '"+hourCookie+"', minute cookie reads '"+minuteCookie+"', ampm cookie reads '"+ampmCookie+"'.");
alert("timer offset is "+endTimeOffset)
```

The first alert reads `"Put together time is '2022, 1, 11, 1, 11, 0' "`,
the second alert says `Invalid Date"`,
the third alert says, `month cookie reads '1'`,
`day cookie reads '11'`,
`hour cookie reads '1'`,
`minute cookie reads '11'`,
`ampm cookie reads 'PM'."`,
the fourth alert says `"Timer offset is NaN"`.

**Do I have to use a different format or something?**

Comment: I've never seen such date format as `2022, 1, 11, 1, 11, 0`. If you have the individual components already, why don't you pass them as independent arguments instead of packing them in a string?

Comment: `currentEndDateForClockNoTZChange` is a string like `'2022, 1, 11, 1, 11, 0'` which isn't parsable by Date.

Comment: 1. I tried ```Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')``` format first, did nothing, then I tried this format from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')` returns a valid date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way:

the way you want to use the Date() constructor is about integers arguments, not a string

```
let
  monthCookie     = Number(getCookieValue('monthUserPref'))
, dayCookie       = Number(getCookieValue('dayUserPref'))
, hourCookie      = Number(getCookieValue('hourUserPref'))
, minuteCookie    = Number(getCookieValue('minuteUserPref'))
, ampmCookie      = Number(getCookieValue('ampmUserPref'))
, currentYear     = new Date().getFullYear()
, monthCookie     = getMonth(monthCookie)
, endTimeNoOffset = new Date( currentYear, monthCookie, dayCookie, hourCookie, minuteCookie, 0 )
, endTimeOffset   = endTimeNoOffset.getTimezoneOffset()
  ;
```